# writing file periodically through windows service

Tags: c#-4.0, service

I was planning to use a windows service to write a file periodically with c# 4.0. Are there any other options to do this?

Comment: There are as many as there are grains of sand on a beach.  Well, maybe not quite that many.  Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a console application, and the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to execute your application on a periodic schedule.  This would allow you to change your schedule easily, after deployment.